# Convert .csv to .xls in Java

Tags: java, csv, xls, xlsx

Does anyone here know of any quick, clean way to convert csv files to xls or xlsx files in java?

I have something to manage csv files already in place and I need the extra compatibility for other programs.

Sample code in addition to package names is always well appreciated.

Many thanks,

Justian

Here's my code thus far. I need to remove the returns ("\n") from the lines. Some of my cells contain multiple lines of information (a list), so I can use "\n" in csv to indicate multiple lines within a *cell*, but xls treats these as if I mean to put them on a new *line*.

The code is modified from the internet and a little messy at the moment. You might notice some deprecated methods, as it was written in 2004, and be sure to ignore the terrible return statements. I'm just using S.o.p at the moment for testing and I'll clean that up later.

```
package jab.jm.io;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class FileConverter {

    public static String ConvertCSVToXLS(String file) throws IOException {

        if (file.indexOf(".csv") < 0)
            return "Error converting file: .csv file not given.";

        String name = FileManager.getFileNameFromPath(file, false);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> al = null;

        String thisLine;
        DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
            al = new ArrayList<String>();
            String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");

            for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) {
                // My Attempt (BELOW)
                String edit = strar[j].replace('\n', ' ');
                al.add(edit);
            }

            arList.add(al);
            System.out.println();
        }

        try {
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

            for (int k = 0; k < arList.size(); k++) {
                ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arList.get(k);
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0 + k);

                for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {
                    System.out.print(ardata.get(p));
                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                    cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                    FileManager.getCleanPath() + "/converted files/" + name
                            + ".xls");
            hwb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

            System.out.println(name + ".xls has been generated");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Update in my answer. Sorry you had to wait a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know if you know this already, but:

- Excel (if that's your real target) is easily able to read `.csv` files directly, so any conversion you'd do would only be a courtesy to your less "gifted" users.
- CSV is a lowest-common-denominator format. It's unlikely for any converter to add information to that found in a `.csv` file that will make it more useful. In other words, CSV is a "dumb" format and converting it to `.xls` will (probably) increase file size but not make the format any smarter.

Curtis' suggestion of POI is the first thing that would come to my mind too.

If you're doing this conversion on a Windows machine, another alternative could be [Jacob](http://danadler.com/jacob/), a Java-COM bridge that would allow you to effectively remote control Excel from a Java program so as to do things like open a file and save in a different format, perhaps even applying some formatting changes or such.

Finally, I've also had some success doing SQL `INSERT`s (via JDBC) into an Excel worksheet accessed via the JDBC-ODBC bridge. i.e. ODBC can make an Excel file look like a database. It's not very flexible though, you can't ask the DB to create arbitrarily named `.XLS` files.

---

EDIT:

It looks to me like `readLine()` is already not giving you whole lines. How is it to know that carriage return is not a line terminator? You should be able to verify this with debug print statements right after the readLine().

If this is indeed so, it would suck because the way forward would be for you to

- either recognize incomplete lines and paste them together after the fact,
- or write your own substitute for readLine(). A simple approach would be to read character by character, replacing CRs within a CSV string and accumulating text in a StringBuilder until you feel you have a complete line.

Both alternatives are work you probably weren't looking forward to.

Comment: Well, I'm using data pulled from a website (one which I have no control over) and they export this data in a csv format. Unfortunately, some programs that I'd like to use the data with require xls files. Yes, it's pointless to "up-convert", but that's an issue with the software that I'm required to use. I've been trying POI with some success, but it seems to hate return characters (\n) which I was able to use in CSV (understandably because commas are the delimiters). I'll post my code above. Any idea how to remove the characters? I'll mark my attempt above.

Comment: @Justian: Skimming over your code, I wasn't able to figure out just which problem you're trying to solve. Are these CRs in the middle of fields, or at the end of records? If they're in fields, should they be replaced by, say, a single blank? Is your code not succeeding at doing this?

Comment: No, it's not. Let's say that I have fields for name | pets | zip code. If I have a multi-line column in csv, like "john | dog (\n) cat | 10000", it will show up as "john | dog " and (next row) "cat | zip". It's hard to show this with stackoverflow's auto-formatting. From what I see, it *should* correct this, but no luck so far.

Comment: FWIW if you write CSV data containing hex `0E00`, Excel often "helps" by converting this to numbers.  You can get around this by some monkeying with CSV import but that's placing a lot of know how on end users so we'd rather just handle the Excel creation ourselves so we can ensure columns don't auto convert.

Answer (score 9):

Copy paste the below program,I ran the program and it is working fine,Let me know if you have any concerns on this program.(You need Apache POI Jar to run this program)

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;


public class CSVToExcelConverter {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList arList=null;
        ArrayList al=null;
        String fName = "test.csv";
        String thisLine;
        int count=0;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
        DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
        int i=0;
        arList = new ArrayList();
        while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
        {
            al = new ArrayList();
            String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
            for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
            {
                al.add(strar[j]);
            }
            arList.add(al);
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }

        try
        {
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
            for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
            {
                ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
                for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
                {
                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                    String data = ardata.get(p).toString();
                    if(data.startsWith("=")){
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                        data=data.replaceAll("=", "");
                        cell.setCellValue(data);
                    }else if(data.startsWith("\"")){
                        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        cell.setCellValue(data);
                    }else{
                        data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                        cell.setCellValue(data);
                    }
                    //*/
                    // cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.xls");
            hwb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } //main method ends
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to read or write XLS or XLSX files in Java, Apache POI is a good bet: http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 3):

The tools in Excel are not adequate for what the OP wants to do. He's on the right track there. Excel cannot import multiple CSV files into different worksheets in the same file, which is why you'd want to do it in code. My suggestion is to use OpenCSV to read the CSV, as it can automatically correct for newlines in data and missing columns, and it's free and open source. It's actually very, very robust and can handle all sorts of different non-standard CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I have something to manage csv files
>   already in place and I need the extra
>   compatibility for other programs.

What are those other programs?  Are they required to access your data through Excel files, or could they work with an JDBC or ODBC connection to a database?  Using a database as the central location, you could extract the data into CSV files or other formats as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small software called [csv2xls](https://github.com/sixro/incubateur/tree/master/csv2xls). It needs Java.

Comment: Thanks @Jaan. Now, it's [here](https://github.com/sixro/incubateur/tree/master/csv2xls).