# Convert .txt file to .xls in java

Tags: java, text, xls

I'm using mallet to do some topic modeling experiment and now I got the keys.txt and doc.txt which I can open using microsoft excel but when I used POI api to read the content it just didn't work and give me the result as invalid header.

I tried to open the files in excel and save them the second time in xls format and this time it worked. So I guess though I specified in mallet command that it should be saved as xls it didn't work.

Is there any way that I can convert a txt to xls format in java? Or I can use java to open call microsoft excel to open the .txt file and save them again?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind adding the source code you've worked with?

Comment: I don't mind but there isn't actually "source code" since I used mallet from the command line and it generated the files. It's ./bin/mallet --input input.mallet --output--keys keys.xls but though I specify it should be in .xls format but actually it's still in .txt format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe mallet is generated CSV (comma separated value) or TSV (tab separated value) files. You could try a library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) to read the file, create an XLS file from the data using POI. If my assumption is true, you may find more help [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189308/convert-csv-to-xls-in-java?rq=1).